# React - After typing more than a character in search bar, it stops fetching users

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, redux, fetch

Case: Search bar retrieves users just fine based on ONE character, once you type a second character, it retrieves nothing anymore.

Example if you wanna look for Andrew, and you type "A", it will retrieve all users that start with A, if you type your second letter, in this case N, it will retrieve nothing anymore.

This is quite a big project I'm working on, long code coming in:

My search bar:

```
Import Select from 'react-select';


<Select
  onInputChange={handleInputChange}
  onChange={userHandler}
  className="searchPlayer"
  options={options}
  placeholder={t('searchBar', {results: totalResults})}
  search={true}
/>
```

handleInputChange:

```
  const handleInputChange = search => {
    if (search) {
      const newFilters = {
        ...filters,
        search: search,
      };
      setFilters(newFilters);
    }
  };
```

setFilters:

```
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
```

userHandler (if relevant):

```
  const selectSearchUserHandler = (data) => {
    history.push(`/accounts/${data.id}`);
  };
```

My useEffect to fetch new accounts:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (status !== 'idle') {
      dispatch(fetchAccounts({ filters, options }));
    }}, [filters, options]);
```

options -> nothing more than an object with the page the user is on + results limit per page. { page: 1, limit: 15 }

My action for fetching new accounts:

```
export const fetchAccounts = createAsyncThunk(
  'accounts/fetchAccounts',
  async ({ filters, options }) => {
    const filterParams = new URLSearchParams(
      Object.assign(filters, options),
    ).toString();
    const {
      data: { data },
    } = await get(`/accounts?${filterParams}`);

    return data;
  },
);
```

Comment: I don't get it, your problem is related to a `select` or an `input`?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it by putting breakpoints? I would put breakpoints in your onChange and onInputChange callbacks, to make sure the correct one is called at the right time, and inside the useEffect to make sure it is being called when the search changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the fact that this callback contains a copy of `filters` and it's never getting refreshed:

```
  const handleInputChange = search => {
    if (search) {
      const newFilters = {
        ...filters,
        search: search,
      };
      setFilters(newFilters);
    }
  };
```

Make sure that you are retrieving a current value of `filters` in the event handler.

Comment: Neal, I'm confused about this one. filters is part of const [filters, setFilters] = useState({}) which is set by setFilters(newFilters) at the end of the function and handleInputChange is called on each key press, while I console.log it, it does properly output whatever it is written inside the input field.

I'm absolutely stuck on this one.

Comment: What kind of component is `Select`? Is that a third party api?

Comment: It's react-select component. I should have mentioned that, I'll edit the post to include it. My bad, thanks for asking, improving the content of the question as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `filterOption={false}` to my react-select element fixed it for me.